# Compare string to binary photo base64encoded PHP

Tags: php

Im converting a photo to binary text. How come when I copy the output and the try to compare it against itself the two dont match? here is part of it

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {

    $image = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $data = fopen ($image, 'rb');
    $size=filesize ($image);
    $contents= fread ($data, $size);
    fclose ($data);

    $encoded= base64_encode($contents);
    $code = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB ...." //etc. the output I previously got from photo

    if($code == $encoded){echo 'success';} // but they dont match
```

Comment: Not clear. So as this image is coming from an image upload, where did you get the previous base64 string from?

Comment: In the last line does encoded have 2 dolllar sign ($$) on purpose?

Comment: yes I previously uploaded the image, echoed  $encoded copied it and pasted it in quotes for the $code variable

Comment: You just updated your code to remove the extra `$` @Juan mentioned without any comment. Was that a typo when posting your code here, or was that in the original code? If it was a typo here, then I'm guessing that this isn't a copy/paste from your original code but a rewrite?

Comment: i typed the last line in

Comment: Please copy/paste all code instead of rewriting it. It's impossible for us to find potential typos/mistakes etc if we can't see the real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. It had to do with my text editor adding a line break because the string was so long. I just deleted the space and they match.